# Looking for ideas to solve issue with WEBAPI style controller in ASP.NET site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I was tasked with implementing a file upload utility to our existing ASP.NET corporate site. This 3rd party utility (Uppy.js) works great but it calls a controller to upload a file and I have a traditional ASP.NET site.  So I added a controller to our ASP.NET Website application and created a JavaScript function which POSTs an image or PDF to the end point /api/docfile.

This code works without issue locally in my DEV environment, however, when I load to a QA box I get an Internal Server Error (500) and I am at a loss as to why.  This is what I am hoping someone might have an idea that can help.

JavaScript

```
var uppy = Uppy.Core({
           locale: localeLib,
           restrictions: {
                    maxFileSize: 20971520,
                    maxNumberOfFiles: 5,
                    allowedFileTypes: ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg']}
                })
                .use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
                    inline: true,
                    target: '#drag-drop-area',
                    replaceTargetContent: true,
                    showProgressDetails: true,
                    note: uploadMsg,
                    proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy: false,
                    width: "auto",
                    browserBackButtonClose: true
                })
                .use(Uppy.ProgressBar, {
                    target: Uppy.Dashboard,
                    hideAfterFinish: false
                })
                .use(Uppy.XHRUpload, {
                    fieldName: 'document_contents',
                    endpoint: 'api/docfile'
                })})
```

ASP.NET Controller called from Uppy.js function above

```
[Route("post")]
public HttpStatusCode Post()
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var docfiles = new List<string>();

        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
        {
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
            var filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileShare"] + postedFile.FileName;
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            docfiles.Add(filePath);
        }

        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);
    }

    return result.StatusCode;
}
```

Global.asax file to allow a Controller to be used within a traditional ASP.NET Website (not WebAPI)

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    internal static HttpClient httpClientInstance;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 500 errors only indicate "something bad happened."  You need the full stack trace and internal errors that the server provided.

Comment: @RobertHarvey agreed and I can see adding something like this.context.AllErrors to the Application_EndRequest in the Global.asax BUT I cannot debug on that server - locally there is no issue so I won't see any errors.

Comment: what server is this running on, i.e. if on IIS, check application logs? what does the inspector network tools show? any inspector console errors on a browser?

Comment: @LinkedListT yes this is served by IIS and the browser console shows: Failed to load resource api/docfile with a 500 error.